# Embed base64 string into pdf PHP

Tags: php, jquery, post, base64

I'm trying to send a chart to server to create a pdf out of it

```
       <form id="pdfform"> <input type="hidden" id="imgbase64" name="imgbase64" > </form> 


var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');    
canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);


       $('#imgbase64').val(dataURL);   
       $('#pdfform').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'controller/sendto_pdf.php');
       $('#pdfform').get(0).setAttribute('type', 'post');
       $('#pdfform').submit();
```

I get this error even tho it's post?

Request-URI Too Large

The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.

"msound's comment" helped get me the string send over, after I have my string how do I embed it into the PDF I've tried a few methods but am not able to get the image in the PDF

```
// Include the main file containing the mpdf class:
include('../classes/MPDF56/mpdf.php');



$base64_string = $_POST['imgbase64'];
$data_img = explode(',', $base64_string);
$data_img_dec = base64_decode($data_img[1]);

function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {
    $ifp = fopen($output_file, "wb"); 

    $data = explode(',', $base64_string);

    fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data_img[1])); 
    fclose($ifp); 

    return $output_file; 
}

$image = base64_to_jpeg( $base64_string, 'tmp.png' ); 

//if($_POST) print_r($_POST);

//
//
// Create an instance of the class:
//$logo="../images/logo_Inet_Sm.png";
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('../css/pdf.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
// Write some HTML code:
$mpdf->WriteHTML('




<div id="container">
   <h4 id ="page_title"><img src="../images/logo_mercury_smaler.jpg"  />  </h4>  
<br />
<br />
<img src="'.$data_img_dec.'" />
 <img src="'.$image.'" />
     <img src="data:image/x-icon;base64,'.$base64_string.'" />
</div>


        ',2); //end pdf html
```

I've tried to save the image to disk then add it to the pdf but when I do the file is 0kb

```
   $base64_string = $_POST['imgbase64'];


function base64_to_png($base64_string, $output_file) {
    $ifp = fopen($output_file, "wb"); 

    $data = explode(',', $base64_string);

    fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data_img[1])); 
    fclose($ifp); 

    return $output_file; 
}

$image = base64_to_png( $base64_string, 'tmp.png' ); 
file_put_contents('/var/www/html/inet/tools/reports/controller/tmpimg/tmp.png',     file_get_contents($image));
```

I've found the correct code I need to save the image to disk and can view it in browser, but when I try to add it to the pdf the image does not show,I do get the other image the logo

```
<?php

// Include the main file containing the mpdf class:
include('../classes/MPDF56/mpdf.php');



$base64_string = $_POST['imgbase64'];

$data = $base64_string;

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

file_put_contents('tmpimg/chart_image.png', $data);


sleep(2);


$mpdf=new mPDF();
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('../css/pdf.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
// Write some HTML code:
$mpdf->WriteHTML('

<div id="container">
<h4 id ="page_title">
<img src="../images/logo_mercury_smaler.jpg"  /> Custom reports and charts 
</h4>  
<br />
<br />

<img src="tmpimg/chart_image.png" />

</div>

',2); //end pdf html


// Output a PDF file:
$mpdf->Output();
// exec('rm -f tmpimg/chart_image.png');
sleep(2);
exit;
```

I tried adding some sleep thinking it needed a few seconds to save the image before I could use it

Comment: Your mistake is you are setting the **type** instead of setting the **method**. This should work: `$('#pdfform').get(0).setAttribute('method', 'post');`

Comment: didn't notice that, thanks that was it.

Comment: Figured it out I had to make it a jpeg then it worked problem solved